# Make the first option selected on Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have the following snippet

```
<b-form-select v-model="form.data_id" :options="datas" text-field="name"  value-field="id">
   <template #first>
      <b-form-select-option value="">Select Items</b-form-select-option>
   </template>
</b-form-select>
```

How to make the Select item selected?

Comment: Set `form.data_id` to be the first entry of `datas` when the component is created.

Comment: Could you please add some examples of the `datas` variable?